# HTML SimpleViwer (gallery viewer) not aligning in Firefox - works in all other browsers tested

Tags: html, css

I have tried relentlessly but I cannot get this element to centre in Firefox. It works on IE, my android phone, and Chrome.

I have a working copy for you to see.

www.novumdesign.co.uk/design.html

```
#header {
width: 900px;
height: 130px;
padding-top: 18px;
z-index: 3;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin specifically (line 195).

With this rule deleted, the gallery element snaps to the centre. But of course the header loses it's alignment.

Also, despite being HTML, the gallery viewer wont load on an iPhone, apparently... Perhaps I should fix the initial issue first?

Thanks!

Comment: First step: Fix your [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.novumdesign.co.uk/design.html).

Comment: The problem itself stems from the floating of the logo image, in combination with `overflow:hidden` that gets set for `.simpleviewer-mobile-glry`. Adding clearing for that class solves the problem as well (and might have less side effects than floating it too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.simpleviewer-mobile-glry{float:left;}
```

fix your problem

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Fixed the issue on the iPhone, too.